# Store JSON data into a variable using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, wordpress

I have an array variable and the value is shown below:

```
var data=[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}];
```

but what I need to get the data value from json url
http://myweb.com/student/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

the url content is:

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"6"}]
```

without semicolon as ending

The question is how to store the value returned from Json into an variable.

Comment: Dont understand your question. Do you have an ajax request which returns data as follows: [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"6"}]?

Answer (score 2):

So, you need to get the JSON data from URL and store in a variable?

**You can do following:**

```
function get_data_from_url(url){
    var http_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http_req.open("GET",url,false);
    http_req.send(null);
    return http_req.responseText;          
}

var data_url = "http://myweb.com/student/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
var data_obj = JSON.parse(get_data_from_url(data_url));
console.log("Data object: "+ data_obj);
```